# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, nuget, hosting

I have tried updating the nuget package, tried replacing i've even deleted the file and re installed but still this is occurring when i try to upload it in My domain hosting in godaddy. 
Previously i had a error that `allowDefinition='MachineToApplication'` beyond application level. I googled it and changet it in my web config. now the problem is with this error. ive even changed the dependent assembly to

```
    <dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

The current version of Newtonsoft.json im using is 7.0.1..
can any one guide me i'm new to this.

[image]

Note: The Hosting which i'm using is plesk hosting and my .net is 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the correct version of the installed version? Else install specific version 7 with nuget

Web.config:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.1" />.
```

Install nuget specified version:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 6.0.8
```

Alternative Web.Config add package:

```
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Comment: I've tried it but no luck!! when i've launched it in  my local host there is no problem the app was working fine but when i ve hosted in my web-hosting in godaddy.com the problem is coming!!!

Comment: Added an alternative solution maybe, in config, search for the record I added, ar add it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall or remove Ref
and reinstall
make sure you are Connected to internet 
just Go to Package manager Console and enter the  Following command

**

> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 7.0.1

**
 Do enter

Comment: ive done that and even updated in my code in web config in my hosting too but still this error is coming

Answer (score 0):

You could try letting NuGet update the binding redirect for you to make sure you have it exactly correct.

Open NuGet Package Manager Console and select your host project in the drop down.  Then enter the [`Add-BindingRedirect`](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console-powershell-reference#add-bindingredirect) command.

Also, double check that version 7.0.1 is the version referenced by your host project and that is the version of the dll making it to the bin directory (right click the dll, properties, details tab, file version).

Answer (score 0):

Running Visual studio 2015 as administrator resolved this issue for me.

Note: My pc is connected to internet.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem please do the following steps

**Step#1**

Delete **Newtonsoft.Json** dll from bin folder if any.

**Step#2**

If you are using web application project go to webconfig and remove these assembly references otherwise delete all assembly references from packageconfig etc.

[image: remove lines]

**Step#3**
Install Newtonsoft.Json again

> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version (Version Number Here)